# Postman Mock Server Call Log empty

Tags: postman

I make a request to my mock server using Postman and receive the expected result. Then I check the Mock Server Call Log and it is empty. I just see a message "No mock server calls yet".
I tried making a request from my own application and again I receive a successful response from the mock server. The Server Call Log is still empty.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the logs are just shown with a delay.

Comment: How much of a delay are we talking about here? I'm around three hours from the first messages today with only messages from four days ago visible.